Build failure EDK2
I get:
d:\edk2\SetVariablePkg\SetVariablePkg.dsc(...): error 4000: Instance of library class [OpensslLib] is not found
        in [d:\edk2\CryptoPkg\Library\BaseCryptLib\BaseCryptLib.inf] [X64]
        consumed by module [d:\edk2\SetVariablePkg\SetVariable.inf]

when I try to compile my EDK2 project.
I am trying to use the RandomBytes() function, so I included <Library/BaseCryptLib.h>. This is what my .dsc file looks like:
[Defines]
    PLATFORM_NAME = SetVariablePkg
    PLATFORM_GUID = 4E85F56A-569F-41FC-AA95-C0C42519E406
    PLATFORM_VERSION = 0.1
    DSC_SPECIFICATION = 0x00010005
    SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES = X64
    BUILD_TARGETS = DEBUG|RELEASE
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = SetVariablePkg/Build

[LibraryClasses]
    UefiLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiLib/UefiLib.inf
    UefiApplicationEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/UefiApplicationEntryPoint/UefiApplicationEntryPoint.inf
    PrintLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePrintLib/BasePrintLib.inf
    PcdLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePcdLibNull/BasePcdLibNull.inf
    MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
    DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibConOut/UefiDebugLibConOut.inf
    BaseMemoryLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseMemoryLib/BaseMemoryLib.inf
    BaseLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseLib/BaseLib.inf
    UefiBootServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib/UefiBootServicesTableLib.inf
    DevicePathLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDevicePathLib/UefiDevicePathLib.inf
    UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib.inf
    RegisterFilterLib|MdePkg/Library/RegisterFilterLibNull/RegisterFilterLibNull.inf
    DebugPrintErrorLevelLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib.inf
    BaseCryptLib|CryptoPkg/Library/BaseCryptLib/BaseCryptLib.inf

[Components]
    SetVariablePkg/SetVariable.inf

This is what my .inf file looks like:
[Defines]
    INF_VERSION = 0x00010006
    BASE_NAME = SetVariable
    FILE_GUID = 53EF0710-78CA-40EF-AFF8-CAC311DBEB38
    MODULE_TYPE = UEFI_APPLICATION
    VERSION_STRING = 0.1
    ENTRY_POINT = UefiMain

[Sources]
    SetVariable.c
    SetVariable.h

[Packages]
    MdePkg/MdePkg.dec

[LibraryClasses]
    UefiLib
    MemoryAllocationLib
    UefiBootServicesTableLib
    UefiApplicationEntryPoint
    UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib
    BaseCryptLib

[Protocols]
    gEfiSimpleTextInputExProtocolGuid

Those are my includes in the header file:
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib.h>
#include <Library/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib.h>
#include <Library/MemoryAllocationLib.h>
#include <Library/BaseCryptLib.h>
#include <Protocol/Variable.h>

#define Buffer 256

I am on Windows 10 and I use the VS2019 compiler. Does anyone know how I could fix the error?

The error message says that you missed defining the instance of the library 'OpensslLib' in your .dsc file.
You can define the OpensslLib as below in your .dsc file
OpensslLib|CryptoPkg/Library/OpensslLib/OpensslLib.inf

For a new similar error, you can search a reference on other .dsc files.
